# Activate Color Picker Overlay When Button Pressed SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI we are lucky to have a native color picker thanks to the `ColorPicker()` view. Unfortunately the way this works is that the view overlays inside the frame it is being put in... I can deal with that and it is not a problem. What I haven't been able to fix is the activation of the view through a button and getting rid of the default circle button.

**What I want to accomplish, illustrated:**

*Press Button...*

[image]

*Get color picker overlay...*
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, there is no direct SwiftUI public API for that, so

**DISCLAIMER: all below is just for demo purpose, if you will use it in real project all consequences are on your responsibility!**

#### Tested on iOS 15-16 as valid!

[image: demo]

As it is clear now the approach is half-hacky, half- because NO private API is used, but -hacky because we reverse-engineer run-time.

Let's go... The `ColorPicker` is just wrapper on the `UIColorWell`, which is `UIControl`, but it does not do anything as control, it is just a container, which has a `UIButton` somewhere inside. So we just need to find that button and activate its action when we need, hiding *ugly* `ColorPicker` at the same time.

Main parts:

```
extension UIColorWell {
    override open func didMoveToSuperview() {
        // ...

        // find a button and store handler with it in helper
        if let uiButton = self.subviews.first?.subviews.last as? UIButton {
            UIColorWellHelper.helper.execute = {
                uiButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

and usage

```
Button {
    // call action in helper 
    UIColorWellHelper.helper.execute?()    // << here !!
} label: {
    Text("Show Color Picker")
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.background(
    // hide standard picker in background
    ColorPicker("", selection: $color, supportsOpacity: false)
        .labelsHidden().opacity(0)
)
```

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestColorPickerOnButton.swift)

Comment: Hello, thank you for writing an implementation for this and an explanation along with it showing how it works, I wonder, you mentioned **DISCLAIMER: all below is just for demo purpose, if you will use it in real project all consequences are on your responsibility!** which I am glad you did, is that related to memory usage or some other issue with the implementation I should be aware of?

Comment: No, it is about run-time reverse engineering, I don't know how AppStore reviewers will take that, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without creating your own **ColorPicker()**, this is the closest solution if you want to use your customized label.

Note: You can't use `Button` for this case because `ColorPicker()` won't trigger.

Also, the **ColorPicker()** only trigger if you tap on the center of the **Text()**.

```
Text("This is a button")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay {
                ColorPicker("", selection: $result)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .opacity(0.015)
            }
```

Comment: I see what you did there, smart, the issue is that the color picker overlay will only appear if that circle with low opacity is tapped, but if the button (or text in the case, which is fine) is larger than that color-picker-button-circle then the user will have to tap everywhere on the text in hopes he/she/they will hit the button... I see a potential solution to this by making the color-picker-button-circle take up the entire text, which is what I will try next, not sure it will work tho.

**Edit: Plan unsuccessful**

Comment: @WiseEye: That is not difficult to make a custom Color Picker view which is more customizable than what we get for free from apple. Right now you have just the option of playing with opacity.